# Library to answer the questions 'Are there any locations mentioned in a particular text? If so: which locations are mentioned?'

Tags: text-processing, nlp

I need to answer those two questions:

1. Are there any locations (in the sense of place: "capital of France", "South of Spain", "London", "New Zealand", etc. ) mentioned in a particular text?
2. If so: which locations are mentioned?

And I'm not quite sure what's the best tooling / process for it. And maybe what keywords I have to watch out for.

I heard good things about `word2vec` but I'm not quite sure whether it is suitable here.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SE! I may be out of depth here but what do you exactly mean by locations?

Comment: Location in the sense of a place. For example "capital of France", "South of Spain", "London", "New Zealand", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, identifying locations in a piece of text isn't too difficult. The process of [Named Entity Recognition (NER)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) does it.
Depending on the text, you can use libraries like [SpaCy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaCy) and [Apache NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_OpenNLP) (better for simpler tasks) OR you can train your own models (better suited for more domain-specific tasks like identifying names of football stadiums).

However, in the text like 'capital of France' libraries like SpaCy would identify 'France' as a location and not the entire piece 'capital of France'.